# OSMnx edges geometry attribute missing

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx

I'm using OSMnx to extract shapes of roads. However, I found that some ways in OSM seem to be only partially represented geometrically in OSMnx.

A reproducible example that you can run on [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) :

```
<union>
  <bbox-query s="43.604437753042106" w="1.4469172178876575" n="43.60670421020654" e="1.4497628267951939"/>
  <recurse type="up"/>
</union>
<print mode="meta"/>
```

And the command to load this graph with OSMnx :

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(43.60670421020654, 43.604437753042106, 1.4497628267951939, 1.4469172178876575, network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(G)
```

If we take the example of the way 32021916, inspecting the G variable with a debugger shows that G._pred contains 2 edges representating that way :

- from node 2271536804 to its predecessor node 359203175 : the associated edge contains a geometry attribute.
- from node 359203175 to its predecessor node 359203168 : the associated edge doesn't contain any geometry attribute, why ?

However, the plotted graph is complete and displays this road's portion. So my question is : how do I get the complete geometry property for this road ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the solution from the code of the `plot_graph` function : [github repo](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/4d38683ab25556c15996727e02ddbeccdf7494fe/osmnx/plot.py#L381)

The plot function draw a straight line between the 2 nodes if geometry is not defined.